# Ubuntu not display the remote desktop properly?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, putty, vncviewer

I am using:

- PuTTY [release 0.63]
- TightVNC Viewer for windows [version 2.7.10]
- windows server 2012 r2 on Windows Azure.

To connect remote desktop of my Ubuntu machine on windows azure [**Ubuntu 13.10**]. I have installed desktop and get the result of the command `vncserver -geometry 1440x900` like below:

```
New 'paulubuntu:1(azureuser)' desktop is paulubuntu:1
Starting applications specified in /home/azureuser/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/azureuser/.vnc/paulubuntu:1.log
```

and then open the the vncviewer, enter my password correctly, the only screen display to me is a gray screen with the following 3 lines in it:

1. Accept clipboard from viewers.
2. Send clipboard to viewers.
3. Send primary selection to viewers.

Is there some issue to display my desktop? I am newbie to Linux system, any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to connect to "your desktop" via VNC, you should probably use the default 'Desktop Sharing' application (vino-server) that is provided as part of the ubuntu-desktop package, rather than a separate `vncserver` session. You can configure it by entering 'Desktop Sharing' in the dash search, or from the command line by running* `vino-preferences`.

---

Standalone vncservers (such as `vnc4server` and `tightvncserver`) use their own session startup file located at `$HOME/.vnc/xstartup`, and the default file that ships with the package just starts a simple X terminal window on a plain gray root window (which is probably what you're seeing).

You can find a sample `$HOME/.vnc/xstartup` file in the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki at [VNC/Servers - Customizing your session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Customising_your_session) which you can copy and edit to start your chosen desktop session - which must sorrespond to one of the available `.desktop` files in your `/usr/share/xsessions` directory. Note that the `ubuntu-2d` session referred to in the Wiki is no longer available in 13.10.